# Listview not updating after DB insert

Tags: android, listview

I know there are numerous posts on this subject and I think I have read them all but none helping me...

I have a ListView in one activity which is populated with a cursor from a DB and that all works fine.

I then have a button on the screen which starts a new activity where the user can add a new entry to the list.

Once this is done, the first activity is re-displayed BUT the recently added entry is not in the list. If I stop and re-start the app, the new entry is correctly displayed.

I have tried a couple of variations - none produce any error.

This is my main code:

```
public class FirstScreenActivity extends ListActivity {

public static String TAG = "My App:";

//This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
public SimpleCursorAdapter vehAdapter;

    static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {dbMain.ENTRY_ID, dbMain.VEHICLE_NAME};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create/prepare database
    mpgDBHelper mpgDBhelp = new mpgDBHelper(this.getBaseContext());
    SQLiteDatabase mpgDB = mpgDBhelp.getWritableDatabase();

    //Display vehicles available - first get any entries

    Cursor mpgCur = mpgDB.query(dbMain.TABLE_NAME, PROJECTION, null, null, null, null, null);

    // build a listView
    String[] fromColumns = {dbMain.VEHICLE_NAME};
    int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1};

    vehAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mpgCur, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
    setListAdapter(vehAdapter);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);
}

public void createNewVeh(View view) {
    // create intent to start another activity
    Intent newVehIntent = new Intent(this, createNewVehicleActivity.class);

    startActivity(newVehIntent);

    // I have tried putting the update lines here but also did not work
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

        Log.v(TAG, "In onResume...about to reset list");

    // Refresh ListAdaptor  
        //vehAdapter.getCursor(); <-- this doesn't work either
    vehAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

In the code for the other activity, I just use:

```
finish();
```

...after the DB insert.

I am getting the log message from the onResume - any suggestions?

Comment: I think it's better to startActivityForResult and update the adapter in onActivityResult method instead of in onResume(). Have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't no - why is that better?

Comment: Method `onResume()` is also called i.e. after lock and unlock the phone and that's the case when you don't need to update the data from database since they probably didn't changed.

Comment: Makes sense - but not going to bother because I've spent too long on this already :-) - but thanks for replying.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Well it's true it doesn't affect the functionality, it's just an optimization of your app to not perform unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the cursor again after data changed and then swap it with current cursor and notify change to adapter:

```
Cursor mpgCur = mpgDB.query(dbMain.TABLE_NAME, PROJECTION, null, null, null, null, null);
vehAdapter.swapCursor(mpgCur);
vehAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

There's no need to create the adapter again.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are running list initialization in `onCreate` method. Just move this part:

```
Cursor mpgCur = mpgDB.query(dbMain.TABLE_NAME, PROJECTION, null, null, null, null, null);

// build a listView
String[] fromColumns = {dbMain.VEHICLE_NAME};
int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1};

vehAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mpgCur, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
setListAdapter(vehAdapter);
```

to `onResume()`

Comment: I want the list to display as soon as the app starts - is onResume called then? If it is, I'm just re-querrying and re-declaring everything every time - seems very inefficient?

Comment: yes, onResume is calling right on application start

Comment: OK, that works - many thanks, although I'm not happy about it - seems like I'm doing manually what the listAdapter is supposed to do automatically, according to the Android tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Cursor isn't updated, though the data have changed. You may requery (that is make another query and obtain a new `Cursor` instance).

Comment: But I'm using a special list adapter linked to a cursor - according to the tutorial, the whole point is to enable you to just tell the cursor to re-query and it all gets done for you. Yes, I can write my own code to do the query and re-display every time but surely missing the point?

Comment: I understand, but i also know that `Cursor.requery()` is deprecated. So even if this method would actually do its job, its good practise not to use it ;)